# In c++, my program automatically goes to the next CIN prompt without letting the user add input

Tags: c++, cin, cout, endl

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SENIOR_PRICE = 9;
const int ADULT_PRICE = 12;
const float CHILD_PRICE = 6.95;
const float TAX_RATE = .06;

int main()
{
        string name;
        string address;
        int numSeniorTickets;
        int numAdultTickets;
        int numChildTickets;

        cout << "Enter customer name:" << endl;
        cin >> name;

        cout << "Enter customer address:" << endl;
        cin >> address;

        cout << "How many senior season tickets?" << endl;
        cin >> numSeniorTickets;

        cout << "How many adult tickets?" << endl;
        cin >> numAdultTickets;

        cout << "How many child tickets?" << endl;
        cin >> numChildTickets;

        return 0;
}
```

After the user enters their name, they are then prompted to enter their address. But before they can enter their address it also prompts for the number of senior season tickets. Why is it skipping a line of input? Here's what happens:

```
Enter customer name:
Daniel Benson
Enter customer address:
How many senior season tickets?
5
How many adult tickets?
5
How many child tickets?
5
```

Comment: This is Because the trailing '\n' from the name input. cin in case of strings leaves the  newline character in the input buffer and when the next cin is called it takes the newline from the buffer and dont wait for user input. Try flushing the buffer before taking the next string.

Comment: I am pretty new to c++ programming. What do you mean by flushing the buffer?

Comment: This is really a problem you could easily resolve yourself using your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cin >> name;

Takes the input only upto space. Therefore if you print the variable `name` you will get `Daniel`. And if you print the variable `address` you will get `Benson`. So as far as the program is concerned it has taken in two strings as input.

[A proof of the above statements by printing the variables after input.](http://ideone.com/CMiNRF)

You might want to use [cin.getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) for taking space separated strings as input.

Comment: I didn't realize cin only takes input upto space. I used cin.getline() instead and it works just fine for the strings. Thanks!